# Jenkins Not Reading my sonar-project.properties File

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

So I am setting up a .NET project to be built and scanned with SonarQube`(7.4)` and Jenkins `(v2.173)`.  I am currently able to pull my **.NET** project into Jenkins and build the project correctly using the Jenkins file located in the same directory as the solution file.

Since I have added my `sonar-project.properties` in the same folder as my `.sln` file and tried to get SonarQube running from the Jenkins file.  Upon doing so I get this error when attempting to run SonarQube:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'test_45': sonar.sources
>
> ERROR:
>
> ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

`test_45` is the project key within the properties file.

**sonar-project.properties** file:

```
sonar.projectKey=test_45
sonar.projectName=test-45
sonar.projectVersion=${BUILD_NUMBER}

sonar.source=.
sonar.language=vb

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=Test.01.sln
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.verbose=true
```

**Jenkins File**:

```
stage("SonarQube Analysis") {
    steps {
         script {
            def SONARSCANNER = tool "Sonar";
            withSonarQubeEnv("Sonar") {
                 bat "${SONARSCANNER}/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227/bin/sonar-scanner.bat"
         }
    }
}
```

I have also used the command within Jenkins with no success.

```
bat "${SONARSCANNER}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:test_45 /n:test-45 /v:45"
```

I've also tried to pass in the parameter `sonar-runner -Dproject.settings=./sonar-project.properties`
into the **Additional arguments** but no success.

I've essentially stripped everything out of sonar-properties file down to **projectKey**, **projectName**, **projectVersion** and **sonar.source** and was able to get SonarQube to scan but would only display the third-party libraries and not any of the VB code within the project.

I haven't seen much on vb projects so that is why I am posting this particular question.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**UPDATE:**

Changed the `source` to `sources` as recommended and now I am able to read the properties file.  I have also changed the language from `vb` to `vbnet`.  Currently, the project is not showing up in SonarQube but runs.

Now getting this error:

> Property missing: 'sonar.vbnet.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf
> files will be loaded for this project.

Comment: You have typo in your `sonar-project.properties`. You have `sonar.source=.` instead of `sonar.sources=.`.

Comment: Thanks @agabrys that seemed to get it to read my sonar-properties file now.  Though it's not reading the vb code and just the xml and javascript files. Would you recommend to exclude those files or include the vb files?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346369/i-have-a-the-next-error-analyzer-results-wont-be-loaded-from-this-directory) open SO question. Are you using the paid vb plugin?